# error: no matching function for call to ‘CBNET::CBNET(boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>::type&)’

Tags: python, c++, boost, compiler-errors

I tried to include a plugin system for python into my C++ project.
I used boost for this (1.54).

I probably have a compile issue and I don't know whats the reason for it or what would be a possible fix:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp:50,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from includes.h:72,
                 from ghost.h:26,
                 from bnet.cpp:23:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::python::objects::value_holder<Value>::value_holder(PyObject*, A0) [with A0 = boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>; Value = CBNET; PyObject = _object]’:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:71:48:   required from ‘static Holder* boost::python::objects::make_instance<T, Holder>::construct(void*, PyObject*, boost::reference_wrapper<const T>) [with T = CBNET; Holder = boost::python::objects::value_holder<CBNET>; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:45:74:   required from ‘static PyObject* boost::python::objects::make_instance_impl<T, Holder, Derived>::execute(Arg&) [with Arg = const boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>; T = CBNET; Holder = boost::python::objects::value_holder<CBNET>; Derived = boost::python::objects::make_instance<CBNET, boost::python::objects::value_holder<CBNET> >; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/class_wrapper.hpp:29:51:   required from ‘static PyObject* boost::python::objects::class_cref_wrapper<Src, MakeInstance>::convert(const Src&) [with Src = CBNET; MakeInstance = boost::python::objects::make_instance<CBNET, boost::python::objects::value_holder<CBNET> >; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/as_to_python_function.hpp:27:61:   required from ‘static PyObject* boost::python::converter::as_to_python_function<T, ToPython>::convert(const void*) [with T = CBNET; ToPython = boost::python::objects::class_cref_wrapper<CBNET, boost::python::objects::make_instance<CBNET, boost::python::objects::value_holder<CBNET> > >; PyObject = _object]’
/usr/include/boost/python/to_python_converter.hpp:88:9:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp:229:80:   required from ‘static void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<T, X1, X2, X3>::register_aux2(T2*, Callback) [with T2 = CBNET; Callback = boost::integral_constant<bool, false>; T = CBNET; X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp:219:60:   required from ‘static void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<T, X1, X2, X3>::register_aux(void*) [with T = CBNET; X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]’
/usr/include/boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp:205:43:   required from ‘static void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<T, X1, X2, X3>::register_() [with T = CBNET; X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]’
/usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:507:29:   required from ‘void boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::initialize(boost::python::no_init_t) [with W = CBNET; X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]’
/usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:638:5:   required from ‘boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::class_(const char*, boost::python::no_init_t) [with W = CBNET; X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]’
bnet.cpp:4049:31:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp:137:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘CBNET::CBNET(boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>::type&)’
             BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1ST(N, BOOST_PYTHON_UNFORWARD_LOCAL, nil)
             ^
/usr/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp:137:13: note: candidates are:
bnet.cpp:50:1: note: CBNET::CBNET(CGHost*, std::string, std::string, std::string, uint16_t, uint32_t, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, uint32_t, std::string, std::string, std::string, char, bool, bool, bool, unsigned char, BYTEARRAY, BYTEARRAY, std::string, std::string, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint8_t)
 CBNET :: CBNET( CGHost *nGHost, string nServer, string nServerAlias, string nBNLSServer, uint16_t nBNLSPort, uint32_t nBNLSWardenCookie, string nCDKeyROC, string nCDKeyTFT, string nCountryAbbrev, string nCountry, uint32_t nLocaleID, string nUserName, string nUserPassword, string nFirstChannel, char nCommandTrigger, bool nHoldFriends, bool nHoldClan, bool nPublicCommands, unsigned char nWar3Version, BYTEARRAY nEXEVersion, BYTEARRAY nEXEVersionHash, string nPasswordHashType, string nPVPGNRealmName, uint32_t nMaxMessageLength, uint32_t nHostCounterID, uint8_t nup )
 ^
bnet.cpp:50:1: note:   candidate expects 26 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from bnet.cpp:33:0:
bnet.h:79:7: note: CBNET::CBNET(CBNET&)
 class CBNET
       ^
bnet.h:79:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>::type {aka const CBNET}’ to ‘CBNET&’
make: *** [bnet.o] Error 1
```

My include in bnet.cpp (cut):

```
+#include <boost/python.hpp>
+
+void CBNET :: RegisterPythonClass( )
+{
+   using namespace boost::python;
+
+   void (CBNET::*QueueChatCommand1)(string)                = &CBNET::QueueChatCommand;
+   void (CBNET::*QueueChatCommand2)(string, string, bool)  = &CBNET::QueueChatCommand;
+
+   class_<CBNET>("BNET", no_init)
+       .def_readonly("GHost", &CBNET::m_GHost)
+   ;
+}
```

For any source questions, the whole commit can be found here:
https://github.com/OHSystem/OHSystem/commit/2257b168a742d1254847d5668254ea2cde49ff01

The problem is that I have before a file named bncsutilinterface.cpp which include the changes in the same way and there is no compile error.

What is the difference, and what is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to divide-and-conquer. That commit is too large to analyze from just a review.

My hunch is that you should try to disable (comment out) the section that use `boost::ref` like:

```
try 
{ 
    EXECUTE_HANDLER("PlayerDeleted", true, boost::ref(this), boost::ref(player)) 
}
catch(...) 
{ 
    return;
}
```

(there are many such sections). If it removes the problem then it confirms that using `boost::ref` leads to invoking the Boost Python "thingies"¹ using `boost::reference_wrapper<...>` and, as the message implies, this is not supported.

At least for `boost::ref(this)` it seems trivial that you can (should) drop the `boost::ref`  because `this` is not mutable and trivially copyable anyways.

For the other arguments you might need to use `boost::cref` or find another way to pass the reference. Perhaps using reference wrappers here was never necessary in the first place (I don' know).

(Be sure to check that you don't end up copying parameters where you expected references)

¹ I know little about those :(

Answer (score 0):

Your class `CBNET` is copyable. If it is not intended use `class_<CBNET, boost::noncopyable>("BNET", no_init)`

If something is copiable there should be a method to copy and the signature `CBNET::CBNET(boost::reference_wrapper<const CBNET>::type&)` boost python is demanding seems to be something like that (copy constructor).

However I am not sure that this is the actual reason.